# finding xattr recursively for symbolic links rather than their target?

Tags: bash, macos, symlink, xattr

I've been using the following command (in bash terminal) to find the extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment` for files/folders on my system.

```
sudo find "`pwd`" -xattrname com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment -exec printf %s\\t {} \; -exec mdls -name kMDItemComment -raw {} \; -exec echo \;
```

However, the results it returns for symbolic links are the KMDItemComment of their target file/folder.

```
$ sudo find "`pwd`" -xattrname com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment -exec printf %s\\t {} \; -exec mdls -name kMDItemComment -raw {} \; -exec echo \;
/Users/MM/Desktop/test/test.txt this is a KMDItemComment
$ xattr -pls com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment /Users/MM/Desktop/test/test.txt
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment: ,SYMLINK
```

Is there some way I can modify this find command to properly display the KMDItemComment xattr for symbolic links instead of displaying the data from their target file/folder?

I tried using `xattr -pls` instead of the `mdls` command, but for files that *aren't* symlinks, the printed data includes all of the hexadecimal data in addition to the ASCII string for the comment (which is a lot of extra lines of info per-file/folder that I don't want in the output, especially if the comments on the files are particularly long).

```
$ xattr -pls com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment /Users/MM/Desktop/test/test.txt
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemComment:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 5F 10 4B 74 68 69 73 20  |bplist00_.Kthis |
00000010  69 73 20 61 20 4B 4D 44 49 74 65 6D 43 6F 6D 6D  |is a KMDItemComm|
00000020  65 6E 74 20 77 72 69 74 74 65 6E 20 77 69 74 68  |ent written with|
00000030  20 74 68 65 20 4D 65 74 61 6D 65 72 20 61 70 70  | the Metamer app|
00000040  20 66 72 6F 6D 20 65 63 6C 65 63 74 69 63 6C 69  | from eclecticli|
00000050  67 68 74 2E 63 6F 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00  |ght.co..........|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 56                             |......V|
00000077
```